# Generate equation from Simulink Model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a large simulink model with many source and sink blocks, many with only elementary arithmetic operations in between. I have been asked to document the equations behind the model. I am currently doing this manually and I am finding it rather slow and there is a relatively high chance of errors in the process.

Is there any way for Simulink to generate the equations (in MATLAB syntax for example) automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no utility in MATLAB/Simulink that can do exactly what you are looking for (and I personally don't know of any third-party tools that can do this, either).

However, I think that your best bet might be to make use of [Simulink Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-coder/index.html).  This will allow you to convert your Simulink model to C code.  From that code, you may be able to extract the equivalent equations more easily than you can by analyzing the Simulink model by hand.

The catch, though, is that Simulink Coder is an add-on package to base Simulink, so you may or may not have this tool available to you.